# How to determine upper and lower limits of theta for cylindrical volume?

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

> Give the limits of integration for evaluating the integral $\iiint_Rf(r,\theta,z)\,dz\,r\,dr\,d\theta$ as an iterated integral over the region that is bounded below by the plane $z=0$, on the side by the cylinder $r=9\cos\theta$, and on top by the paraboloid $z=3r^2$.
>
> $0\le z\le2r^2$; $0\le r\le9\cos\theta$; what about $\theta$?

What I don't understand is how to get the last one.  I would think the lower limit of $ \theta$ would be $0$, and its upper limit would be $2π$, considering both components of the 3D objects have the full range of rotation for $θ$.  Apparently the answer is ACTUALLY that $-\pi/2 ≤ \theta ≤ \pi /2$.   I don't understand how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: How can you have $0\le r \le 9\cos\theta$ when $\cos\theta < 0?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot of your region is:
[image]

I've drawn the cylinder as a spiral in order not to cover the inside. Let's just look at the equation of your cylinder:
$$r = 9 cos(\theta) $$
$$ r^2 = 9rcos(\theta)$$
Since $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $x = r cos(\theta)$ we have:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 9x$$
$$(x - 4.5)^2 + y^2 = 4.5^2 = r^2$$
From this we can conclude that the angle $\theta$ which lies on the $xy$ plane is bounded by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

[image]
As you can see the argument of $x_1$ is $\pi /2$ and the argument of $x_2$ is $-\pi /2$ (well, almost).